# Edit exif information in iOS

Tags: ios, exif

all:
     I modify exif information of JPG FILE following the codes, but `xcode` always says:

> 2016-12-28 23:28:39.913239 Image[13598:2429980] [Image] ImageIO: CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource:0: One of kCGImageDestinationMetadata, kCGImageDestinationOrientation, or kCGImageDestinationDateTime is required.

I do't know why?and how to modify right.

```
void test1(){
    NSString *path = @"/Users/feinno/Desktop/Aerial01.jpg";
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    CGImageSourceRef isrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge_retained CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);

    CFDictionaryRef properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(isrc, 0, NULL);
    CFMutableDictionaryRef mutableProperties = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, properties);
    NSLog(@"%@", mutableProperties);

    CFDictionaryRef tiffProperties = CFDictionaryGetValue(mutableProperties, kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary);
    CFMutableDictionaryRef tiffProfsMut = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, tiffProperties);

    NSString *value = @"md5: 123";
    CFDictionarySetValue(tiffProfsMut, kCGImagePropertyTIFFModel, (__bridge const void *)value);

    CFDictionarySetValue(mutableProperties, kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary, tiffProfsMut);
    CFRelease(tiffProfsMut);
    NSLog(@"%@", mutableProperties);

    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(isrc);
    NSMutableData *newImageData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGImageDestinationRef idst = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)newImageData, UTI, 1, NULL);

    CFMutableDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(options, kCGImageDestinationMergeMetadata, kCFBooleanTrue);

    CFErrorRef error;
    CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource(idst, isrc, options, &error);
}
```

Comment: `CFDictionarySetValue(options, kCGImageDestinationOrientation, (__bridge const void *)(num));
`

Comment: `CFDictionarySetValue(options, kCGImageDestinationOrientation, (__bridge const void *)(num));
`

Comment: What is num?  What datatype is it?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having great problems with CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource() and changing metadata....